# Counting overlaps of random intervals of measure

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

We have a strictly increasing measure $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$ given by $\mu(0,x):=\int_{0}^{x}e^{X(s)-\frac{1}{2}\ln1/\epsilon}ds$, where $X(s)$ is a mean zero Gaussian field with truncated log covariance $R(|t-s|)=E[X(s)X(t)]=\ln(\frac{\delta}{\epsilon \vee |t-s|\wedge \delta})$.

At some point during our estimates (after doing Girsanov) we end up with having to bound as sharply as possible the following sum:
$$\sum_{\ell\in \mathbb{N}}P\left[a\in (A_{\ell},B_{\ell})\right], $$

for fixed $a\in [0,\infty)$ and $n\geq 1$ (to be taken to infinity)
$$A_{\ell}:=\int_{0}^{(\ell-1)/2^{n}}e^{X(s)-\frac{1}{2}\ln1/\epsilon}e^{R(|\ell/2^{n}-s|)}ds$$
and
$$B_{\ell}:=\int_{0}^{\ell/2^{n}}e^{X(s)-\frac{1}{2}\ln1/\epsilon}e^{R(|\ell/2^{n}-s|)}ds$$

Ideally, we want to get a bound that is uniform in $a$ after taking $n\to +\infty$.

Unfortunately, those intervals intersect eg. $A_{\ell+1}<B_{\ell}$. Is there any framework for studying such collections of random intervals? Have you seen a similar question elsewhere to help learn some techniques?